# dj-stripe referencing a non-existent migration

Tags: django-migrations

I have a django model where I have a OneToOneField to djstripe's Customer. When I run `makemigrations` a migration is created with the following dependency:

```
dependencies = [ ('djstripe', '0011_alter_invoice_charge_alter_invoice_customer_and_more'), ('users', '0007_rename_username), ]
```

Everything seems to be okay locally, but then when I deploy my code it fails with the following error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration users.0008_stripecustomer dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('djstripe', '0011_alter_invoice_charge_alter_invoice_customer_and_more')
```

Our pipeline does not run `makemigrations`, only `migrate`, so this seems a little weird that a djstripe migration is created when I run `makemigrations` locally but then I cannot use it in deployment. Plus, such migration does not exist in djstripe GitHub repository.

```
dj-stripe version: 2.6.1
Python version: 3.9
Django version: 4.0.1
Stripe API version: 2.68.0
Database type and version: postgres 12.9
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an known bug in v. 4 - https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/issues/1649#issuecomment-1117774629

To solve it you'd have to downgrade django to 3.x.x. They should fix it in the next update as well.

Comment: Thank you. That was my bug report :) I reported it there and asked this question here as well. Unfortunately, downgrade is not an option, but fortunately a workaround was not difficult to implement.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you put some words on what you did? I had to downgrade not to waste too much time on it.

Comment: I just replaced my FK relation to djstripe's Customer model to a direct Stripe API call to create a customer and then set its id as a CharField on my User model.